# Unhandled Exception: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_LocalizationsScope) or inheritFromElement() was called before _ScreenState.initState() completed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling initial method to load data from API using initState. But it is resulting me an error. Here is error:

```
Unhandled Exception: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_LocalizationsScope) or inheritFromElement() was called before _ScreenState.initState() completed.
When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
```

My code is:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this._getCategories();
  }

  void _getCategories() async {
    AppRoutes.showLoader(context);
    Map<String, dynamic> data = await apiPostCall(
      apiName: API.addUser,
      context: context,
      parameterData: null,
      showAlert: false,
    );
    if(data.isNotEmpty){
      AppRoutes.dismissLoader(context);
      print(data);

    }else {
      AppRoutes.dismissLoader(context);
    }
   }
```

Comment: is your _getCategories is in builder method ? how did you get context?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You need to call `_getCategories` after `initState` has completed.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();

   Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      this._getCategories();
   });

   // Could do this in one line: Future.delayed(Duration.zero, this._getCategories);
}
```

Also, you could do this on a different way, using [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html).
To make this task easier, you could create a mixin to be added to StatefulWidgets.

```dart
mixin PostFrameMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  void postFrame(void Function() callback) =>
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) {
          // Execute callback if page is mounted
          if (mounted) callback();
        },
      );
}
```

Then, you just need to plug this mixin to you page, like that:

```dart
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with PostFrameMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    postFrame(_getCategories);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Can you explain how this worked?

Comment: Is it a safe solution? what if init is not yet finished?

Comment: I think using didChangeDependencies instead of init state for getCategories is a better alternative to this answer.....because it gets called after init state completes.

Comment: didChangeDependencies can be called more than once. That's why you must avoid using it for this purpose.

Answer (score 41):

Use the [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html) method which gets called after initState.

For your example:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();

  this._getCategories();
}

void _getCategories() async {
  // Omitted for brevity
  // ...

 }
```

Comment: This is could result in multiple calls to _getCatergories() as didChangeDependencies() is called multiple times. So if the _getCatergories() involves network calls or refreshing state, this would be very bad.

Comment: this works not only for this case but also for  this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363665/dependoninheritedelement-was-called-before-initstate-in-flutter

Answer (score 36):

[Adding a frame callback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) might be better than using `Future.delayed` with a zero duration - it's more explicit and clear as to what is happening, and this kind of situation is what frame callback was designed for:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      _getCategories();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

an alternative is to put it inside `PostFrameCallback` which is between `initState` and `Build`.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getData());
}
    
Future<void> getData() async {
// perform fetch logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this problem, override `initState` method:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Use any of the below code here. 
}
```

- Using `SchedulerBinding` mixin:

  ```dart
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // Call your function
  });
  ```
- Using `Future` class:

  ```dart
  Future(() {
    // Call your function
  });
  ```
- Using `Timer` class:

  ```dart
  Timer(() {
    // Call your function
  });
  ```

Answer (score -1):

The best solution i think is use the context from the Widget build. And paste the method _getCategories(context) after the build with the context from the tree. 
So there is no problem with the widget tree.